# How to parse /var/log/pm-suspend.log date to calculate time difference?

Tags: bash, date-time

Date format in `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` is like `Wed 05 Jul 2023 04:55:30 PM +03`, which I think is in `date +"%a %d %b %Y %I:%m:%S %p %z"` format.

How can I convert this date to Unix timestamp in Bash?

Comment: You want to convert a single such timestamp or replace all dates in the file?

Comment: And can you detail how you would be calculating the time difference, between what and what, and what's your code/command for that?

Comment: Between another Unix timestamp.

Answer (score 3):

the command `date` does not accept the input string:

```
Wed 05 Jul 2023 04:55:30 PM +03
```

The nearest compatible would be one of these:

```
Wed 05 Jul 2023 04:55:30 PM
Wed 05 Jul 2023 04:55:30 +03
```

But both of them need compensation for the cut information.

File: date2timestamp

```
#!/bin/sh

# Expects a date string like "Wed 05 Jul 2023 04:55:30 PM +03" as first parameter.
# Evaluate if it's AM or PM
# remove the "AM/PM" string
# and set the time correction for the missing "PM" if necessary.

if [ "${1% PM*}"  !=  "${1}" ]; then
    echo $(( $(date -d "${1% PM*}${1#* PM}" "+%s") + 43200 ))
else
    date -d "${1% AM*}${1#* AM}" "+%s"
fi
```

The resulting timestamp will be in UTC as expected by linux.
The script takes the date string as first parameter:

```
$  date2timestamp "Wed 05 Jul 2023 04:55:30 PM +03"
1688565330
```

---

Easier it would be if you could change the date in the logfile to not use "AM/PM"-syntax. Then just the `date`-command would be enough:

```
date -d "Wed 05 Jul 2023 16:55:30 +03" "+%s"
```

Comment: There is something wrong with the `date` input. According to your script `Fri 07 Jul 2023 12:16:20 PM +03` is equal to `1688764580` but it should be `1688721380` according to https://www.epochconverter.com/ This is because `date -d "Fri 07 Jul 2023 12:16:20  +03"` and `date -d "Fri 07 Jul 2023 12:16:20"` outputs the same result.

Comment: @cermcem It's a hassle with your timezone. As you are in `TZ="+03"`, the results when omitting `+03` are equal, as `date` assumes the local time as the time-string's timezone, if the TZ-value is missing. To see the difference between local time an UTC you have to add `+00`. Check this to see the difference:  `bc <<< "( $(date -d "Fri 07 Jul 2023 12:16:20  +00" "+%s") - $( date -d "Fri 07 Jul 2023 12:16:20 +03" "+%s") ) / 60 / 60"`

Comment: Did this solve your doubts?